# AudioContext decodeAudioData issue on Safari

Tags: angular, typescript, safari, audiocontext, webkitaudiocontext

I want to decode .ogg contents into an ArrayBuffer.

I have following code in my Angular application component:

```
ngOnInit() {
  (window as any).AudioContext = (window as any).AudioContext || (window as any).webkitAudioContext;
  this.audioContext = new AudioContext();
}

myFunction(oggArrayBuffer) {
  this.audioContext.decodeAudioData(oggArrayBuffer, function(buffer) {
    console.log('decoded audio data', buffer);
  },
  function(e) { console.log('Error with decoding audio data', e); });
}
```

This works on Chrome, but on Safari 11, the error is being triggered:

> Error with decoding audio data null

What could I be missing?

Comment: Have a test file?  Which exact Safari version? Mobile or Desktop? Happy to have a look.

Answer (score 1):

As of today, Safari still doesn't support decoding OGG files with `decodeAudioData()`. Since every browser supports a different set of codecs I can only recommend [Decode this!](https://chinmay.audio/decodethis) to check the support of various file types directly in a browser.

The Web Audio API doesn't require the browsers to support each and every codec which is why the codec support differs from browser to browser. But browsers are required to reject `decodeAudioData()` with an `EncodingError` in case they can't decode something. Safari does just reject `null` for some files which is a bug. If you want Safari to behave consistently you could use [standardized-audio-context](https://github.com/chrisguttandin/standardized-audio-context) which has a fix for that.

Comment: Thanks for the info, changing to a different file format did the trick!